# Gradients with Vector

Tags: calculus

Let $\bar{x}$ be a vector. - Compute the gradient $\nabla f.$

Not sure how I should compute the following function: $f(\bar{x}) = \bar{x}^T\bar{x}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is the dot product. I.e. 
$$
f(x_1,.....,x_n)=x_1^2+x_2^2+.....+x_n^2
$$
Making the gradient
$$
\nabla f=(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1},.....,\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n})\\
=(2x_1,....,2x_n)=2\vec{x}
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** Notice that $f$ is the composition of a bilinear map, namely the dot product on $\mathbb{R}^n$, with the identity of $(\mathbb{R}^n)^2$. From there you should be able to prove that $\displaystyle\nabla_uf=2u$.

A maybe more interesting question is to find the gradient of $\sqrt{f}$, namely the euclidiean norm $\|\cdot\|_2$.